# LiveData doubts

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

Lot of doubts on Live data

I call new asynctask service in one activity.the response is list of orders of user .i am showing name and value in the ui from response using JSON parsing.
if I am changed the value in mysql database instantly it will not change in ui.it will change when once I coming from a previous activity then the value change it is perfect.but I want it changes instantly once effect on the database is it possible

But live data means it instantly effect on ui but it doesn't change

Comment: are you changing values in your back-end db server as you said you changing values in mysql? LiveData updates when local database gets updated in SQLite

Comment: yes  i changed in  mysql

Comment: Okay. So It won't update LiveData directly. You need to update the local SQLite database which is observed by LiveData. You can do it by pushing updates from server to mobile client and trigger the db update which will eventually update LiveData